# Can't get data form selectpicker class in my html template

Tags: django-templates

Sorry for my english, not my native. I'm pretty new to html. I'm using django + bootstrap. I'm NOT using php or javascript except copying main javascripts. What I want:

1. Make good-looking options select in the left part of page. In the right part of the page there will be some ... dunno what. Right now there is some text.
2. Send selected options with request.method="POST" to exactly the same page and  in the right part appear information about selected items (Actually, for now, appears form with one CharField in which i wanna show names of selected items). By the way, old text in the right part of page only appears with "GET" method.

I figured out how to make the page to look exactly what I want. But form does not send data. I'm pretty sure the problem is my bad understanding of 'selectpicker' class. Well, that's my html template.

```
{% extends 'mainpages/layout.html' %}

{% block head %} 

{% endblock %}

{% block title %} Calculator {% endblock %}

{% block heading %} Calculator {% endblock%}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
        <form class="row ml-5" action="{% url 'eval' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Select with Search</label>
            <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="auto" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 2" data-live-search="true">
                {% for table_name, els in el_of_tables.items %}
                <optgroup label="{{table_name}}">
                    {% for el in els %}
                        <option> {{el}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add to menu</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
        {% if request.method == 'POST' %}
            {{form}}
        {% else %}
            <p>Тут будут результаты выбора продуктов, сумма их калорий, белков, жиров и углеводов.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

  
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

And some mandatory (for understanding all my included scripts) strings in my base html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  {% block head %} {% endblock %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <style>
    #Log_in_card, #User_card:hover {
      opacity: 1.0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);/* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    #Log_in_card, #User_card {
      opacity: 0.5;
      filter: alpha(opacity=50);/* For IE8 and earlier */
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 20px;
    }
  </style> 
</head>
<body>
...
<!-- END OF BASE HTML TEMPLATE -->
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- END OF BOOTSTRAP -->
  <!-- MODAL SHOWING SCRIPT -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');
    })
  </script>
  <!-- END OF MODAL SHOWING SCRIPT -->
  {% block script %} {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe I didn't include some mandatory scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is some kind of answer:

1. I added this script:

```
<script>
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = []
    selected = $('.selectpicker').val()
    console.log(selected); //Get the multiple values selected in an array
    console.log(selected.length); //Length of the array
    document.getElementById('result of select').innerHTML=selected;
});
</script>
```

2. I deleted all references to requst.method in template. Added attribure: id='result of select' to the

   tag in the right part of page. Thus, with this javascript, my

   tag updates every select I do. I don't need even form to confirm my selected objects. The only thing left — to style my right part of screen. This is my final template code:

```
{% extends 'mainpages/layout.html' %}

{% block title %} Calculator {% endblock %}

{% block heading %} Calculator {% endblock%}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="row ml-3">
            <label class="input-group-text" style="width: fit-content;" for="inputGroupSelect01">Select with Search</label>
            <select class="selectpicker" id="sel1" name="food" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="auto" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 2" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true">
                {% for table_name, els in el_of_tables.items %}
                <optgroup label="{{table_name}}">
                    {% for el in els %}
                        <option> {{el}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
        <p id="result of select" style="color: brown;">Тут будут результаты выбора продуктов, сумма их калорий, белков, жиров и углеводов.</p>
    </div>
</div>

  
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = []
    selected = $('.selectpicker').val()
    console.log(selected); //Get the multiple values selected in an array
    console.log(selected.length); //Length of the array
    document.getElementById('result of select').innerHTML=selected;
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Benefit is obvious — you can update page without even refreshing page. This is big plus to think about using javascript. But I'm really newbie and django+html+javascript ... Well, noone said this will be easy.